# Algorithm optimization : loop to find pair of items in 3D space

Tags: algorithm, loops, optimization, 3d, distance

Here I have not a problem with a code but I am looking for ideas and good keywords to explain and solve my problem. It is all about algorithm optimization.

I have two sets of items, which are points in a 3D space, they all have x, y, z coordinates. I want to pair items from A with items from B if their distance to each other are less than a dmax variable.

```
for i in A do
  for j in B do
    d = sqrt((xAi-xBj)^2+(yAi-yBj)^2+(zAi-zAj)^2)
    if d <= dmax then
      ok
    fi
  done
done
```

For example, I have 100 items in set A, and 50 in set B.
I want to pair items from A with items from B if the Ai and Bj distance is less than dmax.

What I already did but might not be very effective for now. This is, calculating the distances between all items in A and all items in B, but it is quite slow, and I want to know if there is a way to have the same results quickly (because I have like millions of items in both sets).

My first idea was to split the 3D space where the A and B sets are in different parts and assign all points in a voxel, and thus calculate distances between items from A and B in this voxel, this limits the number of distances I have to calculate. The limitation is that the voxels have to superimpose if I don't want to miss any pair. This can generate duplicates but I can deal with it.

I already droped the sqrt fonction to speed up calculations, and I am now comparing d² to dmax² to check if it matchs the condition.

Do you have another idea or keywords (because I am sure there is a better way to explain my problem) that could help me to find a solution to this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: What when an A item has several B neighbors ?

Comment: Not a big deal, a A item can have more than 1 neighbor, they just have to "be paired" in a couple

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is called "fixed-radius near neighbor search". It is commonly addressed with a kD-tree or an octree.

Using a voxel grid is also possible, but it can be inefficient if too many voxels are void. When looking for the neighbors of a given point, you must visit all the voxels that have a nonempty intersection with the sphere centered on that point.

Comment: Thank you for these key words and these tips